# Slide new entry ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Hello i need to display by slide multiple entry by ajax my script work just for one entry

```
var newTxt = ['hello', 'hi'];
for(var i = 0; i <= newTxt.length; i++) {
    $('#txt').prepend('<li class="none">' + newTxt[i] + '</li>');
    $('#txt li:first-child').toggleClass("none", 2000);
}
```

i use css and toggleClass for animation

```
li { width:100px; }
li.none { width:0px; }
```

The animation work with 1 entry but with more not work 
u have solution for display by slide one by one ?

Thanks you

Edit (now its work but all setTimeout exucute in same time)

```
var newTxt = ['hello', 'hi'];
for(var i = 0; i <= newTxt.length; i++) {
 setTimeout(function(y) {
    $('#txt').prepend('<li style="width:0">' + newTxt[i] + '</li>');
    $('#txt li:first-child').animate({'width':'100px'}, 1000);
 } (i), (i * 2000));
}
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/292/ i need to slide first wait slide seconde wait ...

Comment: Sorry for my little english

Comment: do you want to remove `none` class from `li` ?

Comment: no i need to slide each new entry like carousel

Comment: so where is your ajax request. can you share your whole code

Comment: I add code and jsfiddle in this script all slide in same time

Comment: There isn't an ajax request in your code ... :)

Comment: Its good now for view https://jsfiddle.net/HHsxc/301/ @RadonirinaMaminiaina not complet code but my ajax send me a json array just replace var newTxt